# Unable to format or write to USB drive

Tags: linux, mac, usb-flash-drive

By mistake removed USB drive from Mac while copying something to it.  After that, not able to either format it, or write to it.  On clicking "Erase" on disk utility in mac, am seeing this error:

[image: Error screen on trying to initialize disk]

fDisk shows this:

```
Disk: /dev/disk3    geometry: 126717/255/63 [2035712000 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 07    0  47  56 -  765  53  56 [      3016 - 2035708984] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Tried zeroDisk using diskutil which gave this error:

```
$ diskutil zeroDisk force /dev/disk3
Proceed? (y/N) y
Started erase on disk3
Error: -69759: Securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed
Underlying error: 5: POSIX reports: Input/output error
```

I want to format the disk, and am not interested in recovering the data initially copied.  Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Remove the drive.  Hold it over the round receptacle next to your desk.  Let go.  Purchase a new drive at the checkout counter at your local discount store.

Answer (score 0):

The `input/output error` indicates a faulty sector (hardware-wise).

- If you drive is  quite new, you may ascribe the fault to the early removal, and hope the rest is OK. Then you can look for badblocks with `badblocks -w /dev/...`. However, I don't know if and how bad blocks can be marked as such in Apple filesystems (in Linux ext2/3/4 FS, you'd use the `-c` option to `mke2fs`).
- If you drive is not-so-new, it's probably wearing off and there will be more and more errors. Then you should ditch it.